# Pear Mail line breaks

Tags: php

i'm using `.$uType. "\n\n";` in my Pear Mail with a contact type of text/html ... do I need to add in `.$uType. "<br/>";` to get the lines breaks or `.$uType. "\r\n";` ?

Comment: For line breaks in the HTML body, use `<br/>` html breaks.  Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use

```
.$uType. "<br>\n"
```

The `<br>` tag is needed for HTML mail in which you should use HTML 3.2/4.0.1 (and not XHTML) because of mail viewer compatibility.

The `\n` will make debugging easier when you view the source.

This answer is unrelated to pear mail, it's the same for other mail libraries as well.